# ESP32-cam with webserver

Tags: video, webserver, arduino-esp8266, ip-camera, esp32

I want to stream video with ESP32-cam over the webserver. Can anyone guide me or provide me any source of how to do it?

And if we use any media server for it, then which one will be good.

Answer (score 0):

For a starter use the included sample in Arduino IDE with esp32 core 1.04
File -> examples -> ESP32 -> camera -> camerawebserver
Work through it, and learn to use the functions. (99% of the tutorials are based on this basic example.)

Comment: I have same device and was wondering if this example works for this device i bought "https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/163815964277". I have weird character appearing after upload and trying to view Serial monitor output after clicking resetting button.

Comment: You have to select ESP32 AI thinker cam in IDE and uncomment the //#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER  and comment #define CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT out in the example sketch

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Ya, i did that, but it got fixed by changing baud to 115200 in Serial monitor. Now, I can read the output properly but now new issue i am getting error in output saying "[E][camera.c:1049] camera_probe(): Detected camera not supported.[E][camera.c:1249] esp_camera_init(): Camera probe failed with error 0x20004" as same as this issue i found in Github and i tried all tips from here but no luck. "https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera/issues/102".

Comment: Two more tips: Open the cam cable connector place the cable straight and close and check in camera_pins.h under defined(CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER) if #define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1

Comment: I did remove and replace it again straight, but still same issue and there is RESET_GPIO_NUM -1. I have created a screenshot and photo for all of my setup. Please have a look. Let me know if its too blurry ( tried to keep it one image ) https://www.dropbox.com/s/yd59u0x3sbfoam2/My-ESP32-CAM-setup-all.jpg

Comment: Yes everything you did is correct, but as using an UNO as programmer there is/might be a power problem. Power the ESP32 board from a 5v PSU and disconnect the vcc from the FTDI programmer (aka UNO) error 20004 means NO camera detected (might be a HW defect or not enough power)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Finally I got to work it out. I googled like a lot of website and different website have different suggestions and this time it worked. So what I did is I commented out this line and it worked. `//#define CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT`

Comment: That was  what I wrote in my first answer to your question!